# Light object shakily falling downwards and then fading and disappearing after a minute

Tags: identify-this-object

The objects that I see seem to didder downward or across the sky for a minute until the light fades completely. They did not move in a straight trajectory, rather pivoting from side to side. I saw this a few times in the Berkshires mountains in June. Also in New Jersey this past month. I’m wondering if it is in fact a satellite or something else. I have never heard of a satellite moving this way.

Comment: I think you are wise to doubt that what you saw is a satellite; satellite's don't ditter. Their motion is smooth and steady. They do sometimes fade in and out, or occasionally look like they flash or blink, but that's because they're rotating for some reason and different surfaces reflect sunlight differently. Sure sounds like quadcopters with LEDs to me.

Comment: "Berkshires in June" makes me think "fireflies"